# Django: is_valid is changing self.object

Tags: python, django

In my code, you see two print statements. In my form the previously saved value in the database was `emailprevious@gmail.com`. The new value I entered into the form is `emailnew@gmail.com`.

The expected outcome I had from my print statements:

```
emailprevious@gmail.com self.object.email
emailprevious@gmail.com self.object.email 2
```

Actual outcome:

```
emailprevious@gmail.com self.object.email
emailnew@gmail.com self.object.email 2
```

It seems that `self.attendee_form.is_valid(),`is changing the self.object. I couldn't find that behaviour defined in the Django source code from `is_valid()` Can you explain why `self.object`is changing?

```
class AssignAttendee(SuccessMessageMixin, SingleObjectMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'attendees/front/assign_attendee.html'
    success_message = _("Attendee has been successfully updated.")

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(
            Attendee,
            ticket_reference=self.kwargs['ticket_reference'],
            ticket_code=self.kwargs['ticket_code'],
        )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @cached_property
    def attendee_form(self):
        return AssignAttendeeForm(
            prefix='attendee',
            data=self.request.POST or None,
            instance=self.object,
        )

    @cached_property
    def get_consent(self):
        organizer = self.object.event.organizer
        return organizer.contacts.filter(email=self.object.email).first()

    @cached_property
    def consent_form(self):
        return AttendeeConsentForm(
            prefix='consent',
            data=self.request.POST or None,
            instance=self.get_consent,
            email=self.object.email,
        )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'attendee': self.object,
            'attendee_form': self.attendee_form,
            'consent_form': self.consent_form,
        })
        return context

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        # Check if consent already exists which defines if consent entry will be
        # updated or if a new one will be created.
        consent = self.get_consent
        print(self.object.email, "self.object.email")

        # Validate forms
        forms = [
            self.attendee_form.is_valid(),
            self.consent_form.is_valid(),
        ]

        print(self.object.email, "self.object.email 2")

        if not all(forms):
            messages.error(request, _("Please correct the errors in the form."))
        else:
            self.object = self.attendee_form.save()
            if consent:
                consent.first_name = self.object.first_name
                consent.last_name = self.object.last_name
                consent.email = self.object.email
                consent.save(
                    update_fields=['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
                )
                consent.events.add(self.object.event)
            else:
                consent_form = self.consent_form.save(commit=False)
                consent_form.email = self.object.email
                consent_form.first_name = self.object.first_name
                consent_form.last_name = self.object.last_name
                consent_form.organizer = self.object.event.organizer
                consent_form.save()
                consent_form.events.add(self.object.event)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected outcome. The is_valid() is checking to make sure the form is valid i.e. meets all the requirements you have stipulated in your models or your form's clean method. It updates the object with the new data, hence the print 2 statement, for you to save the object if you want. So if you change the email address, and there are no validation errors in the form, then the object saves with the new email when you submit the form, according to your post method. If you didn't call save then it would still print the new email in your console, but when you checked the db it would be the old email.